# ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm using mysql2 on Ruby on Rails, following Ruby on Rails 4 Essential Training by Kevin Skoglund, and I'm on the early chapters where it tells me to access the project by typing 'rails server' and opening 'localhost:3000' on my browser.

Problem is this:
[Connection not Established](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CPPg8.png)

So I cannot access my project, and can't move on with the tutorials.

Also, I noticed something different between my and the tutorial's terminal. In my terminal, before booting WEBrick, it shows this:
/home/jmmaglinao16/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/values/time_zone.rb:282: warning: circular argument reference - now

I'm not sure if it has any connection to the problem but that's what I have so far. Please help me guys. Thank you.

Gemfile:

```
source 'rubygems.org'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.0.0'

# Use mysql as the database for Active Record
gem 'mysql2'

# Use SCSS for stylesheets
#gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.0'

# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
#gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'

# Use CoffeeScript for .js.coffee assets and views
#gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'

# See  for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
#gem 'jquery-rails'

# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: 
#gem 'turbolinks'

# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: 
#gem 'jbuilder', '~> 1.2'

group :doc do
  # bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
  gem 'sdoc', require: false
end

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano', group: :development

# Use debugger
# gem 'debugger', group: [:development, :test]
```

Database.yml:

```
# MySQL.  Versions 4.1 and 5.0 are recommended.
#
# Install the MYSQL driver
#   gem install mysql2
#
# Ensure the MySQL gem is defined in your Gemfile
#   gem 'mysql2'
#
# And be sure to use new-style password hashing:
#   
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  database: #simple_cms_development
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password: mypass
  socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  database: simple_cms_test
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password: mypass
  socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

production:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  database: simple_cms_production
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password: mypass
  socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
```

Comment: Please post your gem file and your `appname/config/database.yml` file.

Comment: It's not the reason for the error, but the ruby version you are using is incompatible with the rails version you are using.

Comment: did you start mysql?

Comment: @FrederickCheung My ruby version is 2.3.0p0 (2015-12-25 revision 53290) [i686-linux]
My rails version is 4.0.0
How do I know what suits well? Thank you for the help.

Comment: @uzaif Yes i checked and it's running.

Comment: did you run `rake:db setup` command?

Comment: @uzaif it says command not found

Comment: are you using windows?

Comment: In `database.yml`, why the database has a `#` before its name? `database: #simple_cms_development`

Comment: The tutorial said to temporarily # it out. I tried removing it but same result.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the '#' in the beginning of the line like here:

#database: simple_cms_development